# Casting List<[KnownType]> to List<T> to match function's return type?

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics, generic-function

I am trying to make a function that generically retrieves data from my MongoDB collections. To do this I have constructed a generic method that returns a `List<T>`.

My issue is that I have to create this `List<T>` to return, but I do so based on the `typeof` `T`. I am not sure what I need to do to please the compiler..

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDocsAsync<T>(
    CollectionTypes collection, // Enum representing my Collections
    FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> search, 
    SortDefinition<BsonDocument> sort = null)
{
    // Get BsonDocuments from the collection based on the search and sort criteria 
    List<BsonDocument> matchedDocs;
    IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> MongoCollection = GetCollection(collection);
    if (sort == null) matchedDocs = await MongoCollection.Find(search).ToListAsync();
    else matchedDocs = await MongoCollection.Find(search).Sort(sort).ToListAsync();

    // Return a List<T>, covert matchedDocs to List<T> if need be
    Type docType = typeof(T);
    if (docType == typeof(BsonDocument))
        return matchedDocs;
    else if (docType == typeof(LogEvent_DBDoc))
        return LogEvent_DBDoc.ConvertFromBson(matchedDocs);
    // ...
}
```

At both of the `return` lines I receive an error along the lines of "Cannot implicitly convert from `List<[KnownType]>` to `List<T>`. Which makes sense to me, because the `typeof` `T` does not necessarily match the `typeof` say `BsonDocument`. But I have made the proper check to do so.

**Can I cast `List<[KnownType]>` to `List<T>`?**

Comment: Having if statements to check the generic type seems to defeat the purpose of using generics in the first place.

Comment: If you asked me, you shouldn't change what you return based on the type that it is called with.  That decision should go into a separate method from the callee through a callback of some sort.

Comment: I had tried that and its basically the same error "Cannot convert type `List<[KnownType]>` to `List<T>`", just missing the word implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are abusing generic syntax. Generic code should be *generic*, i.e. work with whatever type you use.

You should have different methods, depending on the type that will be passed in. By all means, make the truly generic parts into its own generic method, which your type-specific methods can call. But have the caller, who already knows what type it's using, pick the appropriate method based on that type, and then just use that type explicitly in each type-specific method.

It's hard to say with the example you have, but if you can provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're doing, I would be happy to refactor it to show what I mean.

Comment: You're correct.. I guess I am abusing the generic syntax. My original thought was to just shove a 7 large functions that basically did the exact same thing into one function. // Maybe if instead of `T` I make the type an interface which defines the conversion function. Though what would be the return type? `InterfaceType.GetListType()`?... // Or I guess I can just cut out the second part and put it back in place of the 7 functions and use the generic `Get..`

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you have the `List<KnownType>` that matches the type of current generic instantiation of `List<T>` you can cast it to the required generic type with the help of intermediate cast to `object`:

```
List<T> GetListOf<T>() {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(String)) {
        var stringList = new List<String> { "a", "b" };
        return (List<T>)(object)stringList;
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Leaving the moral judgement whether you should do so to yourself )